# virtual box reconnect error

Tags: 12.04, virtualbox, windows-xp

I have been using ubuntu and virtual box mounted xp on it, I suddenly experienced this error when I tried to open the folders shared on `Z:`

i have reinstalled guest additions but could not find a solution

The error message is:

```
an error occurred while reconnecting z: to \\vboxsvr\user
the network could not be found
the connection has not been restored
```

Answer (score 0):

Everytime you shutdown the virtual machine, you have to set up your shared folders again, unless you checked `mount automatically` and `make permanent`.